# get error when using npm to download jsdom

Tags: web, npm, jsdom

```
> node-gyp rebuild


d:\csfv\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify>node "c:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\nod
e-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:
34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\nod
e_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd d:\csfv\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

My OS is windows 8.1 preview,
Python 2.7,
vc++2010,
and the C++'s environment varaible has been added,still not work, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You:

```
windows 8.1 preview, 
vc++2010,
```

node-gyp docs:

```
Windows 7/8:
Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop (Express version works well)
```

Comment: on my pc,both vc++2012 and vc++ 2010 are installed!...I don't know why this issue occur..